# Classification algorithm used as Regression algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, regression

There is a continuous data sampled at a given frequency. I wanted to know that is it possible to use a classification algorithm, and use this along with some other functions so as to make it behave as a regression algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

In general - no. Classification is not directly convertable to the regression (the opposite direction is much easier). You could obviously create some finite set of "buckets" of values and treat them as labels but in general I have never seen it perform better than even simpliest regressors. Why would you want to do something like this? Why do not use **regressors** for **regression** tasks?

Comment: I was just training a data, and I found an error of 15-16% using regressor. I am thinking, that maybe using classification algorithm would solve the purpose.

Comment: Well as I said in the answer, switching to classification should rather decrease your scores, not increase them. Instead you should analyze better regressors, work with regularization, ensembles etc.